# Python confusing function reference

Tags: python, list, reference

Can anyone explain to me why the two functions below `a` and `b` are behaving differently. Function `a` changes `names` locally and `b` changes the actual object.

Where can I find the correct documentation for this behavior?

```
def a(names):
    names = ['Fred', 'George', 'Bill']

def b(names):
    names.append('Bill')

first_names = ['Fred', 'George']

print "before calling any function",first_names
a(first_names)
print "after calling a",first_names
b(first_names)
print "after calling b",first_names
```

Output:

```
before calling any function ['Fred', 'George']
after calling a ['Fred', 'George']
after calling b ['Fred', 'George', 'Bill']
```

Comment: A good primer of python names, assignment, etc.: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function `a` creates a new, local variable `names` and assigns list `['Fred', 'George', 'Bill']` to it. So this is now a different variable from the **global** `first_names`, as you already found out.

You can read about modifying a list inside a function [here](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch09.html#pure-functions-and-modifiers).

One way to make function `a` behave the same as function `b` is to make the function a **modifier**:

```
def a(names):
    names += ['Bill']
```

Or you could make a **pure** function:

```
def c(names):
    new_list = names + ['Bill']
    return new_list
```

And call it:

```
first_names = c(first_names)
print first_names
# ['Fred', 'George', 'Bill']
```

A pure function means it doesn't change the state of the program, i.e. it doesn't have any side effects, like changing global variables.

Answer (score 7):

Assigning to parameter inside the function does not affect the argument passed. It only makes the local variable to reference new object.

While, `list.append` modify the list in-place.

If you want to change the list inside function, you can use slice assignment:

```
def a(names):
    names[:] = ['Fred', 'George', 'Bill']
```